# Qual a iferença entre super(Pai, self).__init__() e super().__init__ no Python3+?

Tags: python-3.x

Neste código que estou estudando ele declara da forma `super(RandomWalker, self).__init__()`, mas sempre vejo dizerem que em Python3+ pode ser dito como `super().__init__()`:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from .randomwalker2D import RandomWalker2D as RW2D


class RandomWalker(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_grad, max_backprop = True)
        super(RandomWalker, self).__init__()
        self.rw = RW2D
        self.num_grad = num_grad
        self.max_backprop = max_backprop
```

Mas quando altero para `super().__init__()` e tendo rodar parece que fica em um looping. Porque isso acontece se tecnicamente são a mesma coisa?

Todo o código está no git `https://github.com/hci-unihd/pytorch-LearnedRandomWalker`.
Tenho esta duvida faz um tempo, mas nunca encontro a resposta que explique oque realmente preciso.

Comment: O ideal seria colocar uma versão reduzida da superclasse e subclasse, para reproduzir o problema com o mínimo possível de código. Apontar repositórios externos não é considerada boa prática no SO.

Comment: Entendo, pelo visto era minha maquina que estava lenta, estou tendo o mesmo desempenho com os dois modos (como esperado). Obrigado por esclarecer, agora tenho mais clareza de como utilizar super().

Answer (score 0):

A diferença entre `super(RandomWalker, self).__init__()` e `super().__init__()` é que o primeiro é usado para chamar o construtor da classe pai (RandomWalker) e o segundo é usado para chamar o construtor da classe mais próxima na hierarquia de herança. No seu caso, a classe RandomWalker não tem uma classe pai, então o segundo não fará nada.